# Can you say "history alumni"?

Tags: word-choice

Does the word "alumni"/"alumnus" always pertain to a particular university or school, or can you say e.g. "history alumni" meaning all the people who graduated in history at any university (e.g. in some particular geographical region)?

Would "history graduates in France" be more correct?

Thank you

Comment: I get a lot of web hits for "history alumni" but it seems to be chiefly for people who graduated in history from a particular university. Nonetheless, you do get a lot of extended uses of "alumni" (people who've completed any kind of educational course) - my main concern would be that it's not precise, so if you want to indicate people who graduated with undergraduate degrees in history rather than lower or higher qualifications, or from institutions other than universities, you will have to specify that.

Comment: It's also very AmEng. It's not a term I ever encountered in the UK until the greater exposure to US TV over the past 30 years or so.

Answer (score 3):

The word *alumnus* is etymologically related to the idea of nourishment, and is intended to convey the idea that the person to whom the term is applied has been intellectually nourished by a particular institution. The implication is that one has been partially formed as a person by that institution and consequently feels some bond of loyalty to it (somewhat analogous to the bond one feels to one's family). Being an *alumnus* is a binary relationship: one is always an alumnus **of** a particular institution.

The nature of that relationship, at least as it is conceived in the US (and the term is not much used elsewhere), is such that it cannot exist between a person and an academic discipline considered in the abstract. The phases such as *history alumni* may consequently be used only when the context makes it clear that one is referring to those who hold the degrees in history from a particular university, i.e. to narrow down the group one is referring to, but never to widen it across different universities. When one needs to do the latter, one would normally use a different term, such as *history graduates*.

Comment: This does cry out for references and a defense against the charge of etymological fallacy.